# Cancel function of AJAX fired from misc/ajax.js

Tags: ajax

How can I override Drupal.ajax written in misc/ajax.js?

I need to check URL existence before firing an AJAX call.

Is there any other way/better way to achieve that without overriding this js?

Thanks

Comment: It's JavaScript so you can just literally override it. Perhaps if you explained your problem a bit more detail it would be more obvious where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: Hi, thanks @clive, Here is my problem in detail: I'm working on a social sharing site like facebook in Drupal. So there will be more than one user online at a time. There is a facility in site to create a post (like status in facebook) and user can reply/comments to that post. (this reply/comment is submitted using AJAX).

Comment: Now consider a scenario in which A user has made post, another user B goes to his profile and see his post, now user A deletes his post, user B has not refreshed his page so he is still able to see user A's post, now he decide to reply/comment to user A's post, but as user A has deleted his post, Drupal gives default 404 popup. That AJAX call is fired by Drupal core from misc/ajax.js.

Comment: So I need to override that js so I can write something in cancel function of AJAX when 404 occurs.